# How to extract some data from url using Python

Tags: python

I have an url as follows:

```
https://some_url/vivi/v2/ZUxOZmVrdzJqTURxV20wQ0RvRld6SytEQWNocThwMGVnbFJ4RDQrZzJMeGRBcnhPYnUzV1pRPT0=/BE?category=PASSENGER&make=30&model=124&regmonth=3&regdate=2015-03&body=443,4781&facelift=252&seats=4&bodyHeight=443&bodyLength=443&weight=-1&engine=1394&wheeldrive=196&transmission=400
```

What I need is to get the string after `v2/`, thus `ZUxOZmVrdzJqTURxV20wQ0RvRld6SytEQWNocThwMGVnbFJ4RDQrZzJMeGRBcnhPYnUzV1pRPT0=`

I use `furl` to extract the parameter value. I do it as follows:

```
furl(url).args['category'] // gives PASSENGER
```

But here I do not have the name of the parameter.

How can I do that?

Comment: Split the string and take the element by index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following code:

```
l=url.split('/')
m=l[l.index('v2')+1]
print(m)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need a generalized solution but for the url you have provided in question. Then you can do the following:

```
url="https://some_url/vivi/v2/ZUxOZmVrdzJqTURxV20wQ0RvRld6SytEQWNocThwMGVnbFJ4RDQrZzJMeGRBcnhPYnUzV1pRPT0=/BE?category=PASSENGER&make=30&model=124&regmonth=3&regdate=2015-03&body=443,4781&facelift=252&seats=4&bodyHeight=443&bodyLength=443&weight=-1&engine=1394&wheeldrive=196&transmission=400"
answer=url.split('/')[5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Desired output using `re`.

```
import re

url = "https://some_url/vivi/v2/ZUxOZmVrdzJqTURxV20wQ0RvRld6SytEQWNocThwMGVnbFJ4RDQrZzJMeGRBcnhPYnUzV1pRPT0=/BE?category=PASSENGER&make=30&model=124&regmonth=3&regdate=2015-03&body=443,4781&facelift=252&seats=4&bodyHeight=443&bodyLength=443&weight=-1&engine=1394&wheeldrive=196&transmission=400"
re.findall(r'v2/(.*)/', url)
```

Resulting with `['ZUxOZmVrdzJqTURxV20wQ0RvRld6SytEQWNocThwMGVnbFJ4RDQrZzJMeGRBcnhPYnUzV1pRPT0=']`.

But it's safer to use `split()` the way other mentioned, because when api version changes to `v3` this `re` code won't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The string that you are after is not a query parameter, it is part of the URL path.

In the general case you can use the [`urllib.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlparse) module to parse the URL into its components, then access the path. Then extract the required part of the path:

```
import base64
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs

parsed_url = urlparse(url)
s = parsed_url.path.split('/')[-2]    # second last component of path
>>> s
'ZUxOZmVrdzJqTURxV20wQ0RvRld6SytEQWNocThwMGVnbFJ4RDQrZzJMeGRBcnhPYnUzV1pRPT0='
>>> base64.b64decode(s)
b'eLNfekw2jMDqWm0CDoFWzK+DAchq8p0eglRxD4+g2LxdArxObu3WZQ=='
```

---

The keys and values of the query string can also be processed into a dictionary and accessed by key:

```
params = parse_qs(parsed_url.query)
>>> params
{'category': ['PASSENGER'], 'make': ['30'], 'model': ['124'], 'regmonth': ['3'], 'regdate': ['2015-03'], 'body': ['443,4781'], 'facelift': ['252'], 'seats': ['4'], 'bodyHeight': ['443'], 'bodyLength': ['443'], 'weight': ['-1'], 'engine': ['1394'], 'wheeldrive': ['196'], 'transmission': ['400']}
>>> params['category']
['PASSENGER']
```